# How do i scrape the text in the introduction part

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the text under the introduction part but seem to get a `"[]"` as an output

THE CODE IS:

```
import requests
import bs4
import lxml
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

result=requests.get("https://www.1mg.com/drugs/augmentin-625-duo-tablet-138629")

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")

intro=soup.find(text=re.compile('Introduction')).parent.parent.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "DrugOverview__content___22ZBX"})
print(intro)
```

I am writing the code on sublime text editor and running it on git bash

PS:Do try to give an explanation on how to resolve this cause im a noob at web scraping and cant seem to get the hang of it just yet...thanks

Comment: why do you use so complex method ? why not directly `soup.find("div", {"class": "DrugOverview__content___22ZBX"})` ?

Comment: you don't have to use `re` to search simple text `Introduction`

Comment: are you sure you need two `.parent` ?

Comment: maybe you shoud use `print()` to see what you get with previous element - ie. `print( soup.find(text=re.compile('Introduction')) )` because it should shows you where is problem. It get different element then you expect

Comment: your right about using `soup.find("div", {"class": "DrugOverview__content___22ZBX"})` but it still shows none

Comment: your problem is `soup.find(text=re.compile('Introduction'))` - it gets JavaScript element which has also text `Introduction'`

Comment: I checked `result.text` and probably server sends different HTML then you can see in web browser. Maybe it sends warning for bots/scripts/spamers/hackers. maybe it will need other settings in requests - like `headers` or `cookies`. OR maybe it will need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser.

Comment: idk if this is a stupid question....but by "warnings" you mean , i wont be able to scrape this website ? or do i need to use other libraries like selenium

Comment: thanks for the selenium recommendation....btw one more doubt (this is for future reference) ....should we use selenium when the inspect differs from view page source?

Comment: portals don't like when someone scrape data and  when recognize script/bot then they may send HTML with message that you are blocks - or with Captcha. And then your script has to better simulate real human.

Comment: selenium is useful when page uses `JavaScript` to add elements - `beautifulsoup` and `requests` can't run `JavaScript` and then you can't get elements added by `JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I found this page checks header `User-Agent` - maybe it generates different `HTML` for different devices (phone, tablet, laptop).

But it can't be simple `Mozilla/5.0` - it has to be full `User-Agent` from real web browser.

You can see your `User-Agent` on https://httpbin.org/get - this page is useful to test what script sends to server.

This code works for me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0"
}
 
url = "https://www.1mg.com/drugs/augmentin-625-duo-tablet-138629"

result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
                        
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "lxml")

intro = soup.find(text='Introduction').parent.parent.find('div', {"class": "DrugOverview__content___22ZBX"})

text = intro.get_text(strip=True)

print(text)
```